# Better practice with Spring MVC: Service with non-fixed dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a requirement of compatibility with a new architecture based in Spring 3.2. The requirement is: a http request will come to a controller with an attribute that defines which kind of object is required. For example ...mycontroller/load?objType='obj1'.

My controller will have this structure:

```
@Controller
public class myController{

private ObjectService objectService;

@Autowired
public setObjectService(ObjectService objectService){
    this.objectService = objectService;
}

}
```

So after that, I need to check this attribute to decide which service will I use. For example, this case is Obj1Service (method: "load"). All this services are extended from  ObjectService, so: It is a good idea to swap objectService dependency to Obj1Service / Obj2Service in each incoming call? For example:

```
if(objType.equals("obj1")) this.setObjectService(context.getBean("obj1Service"..))
if(objType.equals("obj2")) this.setObjectService(context.getBean("obj2Service"..))
```

I know that is not a great design, but we need to integrate this new modules with other system that produces this kind of http requests.
It is necessary the inheritance because we have very similar behavior in many service's code, but with modifications in internal methods, so part of the behavior will be placed in ObjectService (it is not abstract) and other portion of the code will be placed in it children. Is there another way, more appropriate, to do this? Or you consider that is an acceptable solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have a map of types to services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `map` for all of your services, and get the appropriate service inside each controller method.

Let's say you have two services:

```
@Service("obj1")
public class ObjectServiceImpl1 implements ObjectService {
    ...
}

@Service("obj2")
public class ObjectServiceImpl2 implements ObjectService {
    ...
}
```

In your controller:

```
private Map<String, ObjectService> objectServices;

@Autowired
public setObjectServices(Map<String, ObjectService> objectServices){
    this.objectServices= objectServices;
}
```

Spring will inject the map with all the `ObjectService` beans mapped by their names.

In `load?objType=obj1` handler, you would have something like:

```
objectServices.get("obj1").doSomething(); // will use ObjectServiceImpl1
```

The same with `load?objType=obj2` handler:

```
objectServices.get("obj2").doSomething(); // will use ObjectServiceImpl2
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks! It was what I was searching for!!